# Filling a matrix with content from file

Tags: java, matrix

I'm getting an error on my code. The goal is to add the contents of a file to a matrix.Then ill eventually need to parse it to add it to a graph so that i can eventually perform a depth-first search on it. But until then i need to figure this error out.   I can't figure out what exactly is causing the error. so any help would be nice.
Here is the error im getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
        at DelivA.<init>(DelivA.java:53)
        at Prog340.actionPerformed(Prog340.java:120
```

Here is the class i wrote.

```
public DelivA(File in, Graph gr) {
        inputFile = in;
        g = gr;
        // Get output file name.
        String inputFileName = inputFile.toString();
        String baseFileName = inputFileName.substring(0, inputFileName.length() - 4); // Strip off ".txt"
        String outputFileName = baseFileName.concat("_out.txt");
        outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
        if (outputFile.exists()) { // For retests
            outputFile.delete();
        }
        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.err.format("Exception: %s%n", x);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // --------------------------------Deliverable
        // A-------------------------------------------//

        FileReader f1 = null;

        int c = 0;
        int r = 0;
        try {
            f1 = new FileReader(inputFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f1);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String splitLine[] = line.split(" ");
            c = splitLine.length;
            r++;
        }
        String[][] matrix = new String[c][r];
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f1);
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            String words = s1.next(); // will scan each row of the file
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                char ch = words.charAt(col); // will put each character into array
                matrix[row][col] = String.valueOf(ch);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here:

```
String words = s1.next():
```

You are not verifying if there is any line available.

You should do something like this:

```
...
     Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f1);
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
                if (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    String words = s1.next(); // will scan each row of the file
...
```

Of course you should rethink the code logic accordingly...